# Trying to Set Certificate and Provisioning Profile in Github Actions For xcodebuild archive

Tags: xcode, github-actions

I have a simple GH actions workflow yaml with the following:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    defaults:
      run: 
        shell: bash
        working-directory: working_directory_here

    steps:

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install the Apple certificate and provisioning profile for Xcode
        env:
          BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 }}
          P12_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}
          BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64 }}
          KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
        run: |
          # create variables
          CERTIFICATE_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_certificate.p12
          PP_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/build_pp.mobileprovision
          KEYCHAIN_PATH=$RUNNER_TEMP/app-signing.keychain-db

          # import certificate and provisioning profile from secrets
          echo -n "$BUILD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64" | base64 --decode --output $CERTIFICATE_PATH
          echo -n "$BUILD_PROVISION_PROFILE_BASE64" | base64 --decode --output $PP_PATH

          # create temporary keychain
          security create-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security set-keychain-settings -lut 21600 $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security unlock-keychain -p "$KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD" $KEYCHAIN_PATH

          # import certificate to keychain
          security import $CERTIFICATE_PATH -P "$P12_PASSWORD" -A -t cert -f pkcs12 -k $KEYCHAIN_PATH
          security list-keychain -d user -s $KEYCHAIN_PATH

          # apply provisioning profile
          mkdir -p ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
          cp $PP_PATH ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles

      - name: Install 
        run: pod install

      - name: Build
        run: xcodebuild -workspace something.xcworkspace -sdk iphonesimulator -scheme Development build

     - name: Deploy
        run: |
          xcodebuild clean -workspace something.xcworkspace -scheme Development
          xcodebuild archive -workspace something.xcworkspace -scheme Development -archivePath something.xcarchive -destination generic/platform=iOS
```

The Apple certificate and provisioning profile is taken from [this article in Github](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-xcode-applications/installing-an-apple-certificate-on-macos-runners-for-xcode-development#creating-secrets-for-your-certificate-and-provisioning-profile). The `pod install`, `xcodebuild build`, and `xcodebuild clean` commands all work even without the Apple certificate step.

My `xcodebuild archive` step fails with this error:

```
error: No profiles for 'something.something.development' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'something.something.development'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile.
```

Is there something basic that is missing here? Adding `-allowProvisioningUpdates` does not make a difference -- it will still fail but no error is returned at all in Github Actions output, including with debug mode enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing parameters in the command line, here I would say `provisioningProfiles` parameter in particular.

To make sure you can run the command correctly you can:

1. Open Xcode on your development machine and disable automatic signing if not already unchecked
2. Still in Xcode, select your scheme and then run `Product` > `Archive` from the menu. Click on `Distribute app` in the new window and go through the steps. Make sure you select a valid provisioning profile and certificate at this step. Go to the end and just export (don't go to the AppStore), Xcode will generate you an export folder. You should see a file named `ExportOptions.plist` in this folder, similar to the following:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
       <dict>
           <key>destination</key>
           <string>export</string>
           <key>method</key>
           <string>app-store</string>
           <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
           <dict>
               <key>your.bundle.id</key>
               <string>Provisioning Profile name</string>
           </dict>
           <key>signingCertificate</key>
           <string>Apple Distribution</string>
           <key>signingStyle</key>
           <string>manual</string>
           <key>teamID</key>
           <string>123ABC12</string>
       </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
3. Open the exported folder and look for a file named `ExportOptions.plist`. This file basically contain the arguments that you should pass to your CI command line to mimic what Xcode does locally
4. Encode this file as base64 and store it as a Github Actions secret, e.g. `IOS_EXPORT_OPTIONS_PLIST`
5. Resolve the file in your Github Action step and decode it from base64, store it somewhere, say $EXPORT_OPTIONS_PATH
6. Run your command line with with this added option: `xcodebuild archive -yourparams -exportOptionsPlist $EXPORT_OPTIONS_PATH`

Note: You can run `xcodebuild -h` to see all the available options that you can add to the ExportOptions.plist file.